# What kind of JSON JOLT Spec to get key-value output where key is a data value and value is an array

Tags: arrays, json, key, jolt

I'm trying to find a spec array that yields the desired output

Input:

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "masterId": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1Q52",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "serialNumbers": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "3R24Z3",
                "count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "526GA2",
                "count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": "873XHE",
                "count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Spec:
Trying to figure this out

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "1Q52": ["3R24Z3", "526GA2", "873XHE"]
}
```

My current Spec array is

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "aggregations": {
        "masterId": {
          "buckets": {
            "*": {
              "key": "key",
              "serialNumbers": {
                "buckets": {
                  "*": {
                    "key": "key"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and my current output is

```json
{
  "key" : [ "1Q52", "3R24Z3", "526GA2", "873XHE" ]
}
```

What kind of spec array could give me the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go 4 level up and grab the value to be the key for the array by using `"key": "@(4,key)"` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "aggregations": {
        "masterId": {
          "buckets": {
            "*": {
              "serialNumbers": {
                "buckets": {
                  "*": {
                    "key": "@(4,key)"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where `:` and then triple `{` character traverse is counted in order to reach the desired key value.

[image]

Comment: Hi @AmrutKulkarni . You can check out [my former answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a5841306%20%5bjolt%5d) , [Jolt's releases](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases) and [baazarvoice/jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) . Have a nice work.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks

Mind explaining the mechanics behind this? I'm very new to JOLT. I've had trouble finding good resources on how to learn it, but it's used regularly at my work.

Are there any good resources explaining JOLT, especially how to use #, $, and @ and how to grab data from parts of the JSON doc like your spec array did

Comment: Thanks! I will check those out
I'm hoping to understand Jolt better since it's used very regularly to format data pulled from our db so our middleware can use it